# colorbox + asp.net button wont postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, colorbox

I'm using the colorbox modal plugin (http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)

I've got a simple form sitting in a master page, for some reason I cannot get the submit button to post back, it doesn't do anything at all.

Seems to be a problem a few people are having, but I cant find a fix.

Here' some code I'm playing with, any clues?

---

**Code in Masterpage**

```
<link href="http://www.communitysectorservices.org.au/css/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.communitysectorservices.org.au/js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
        $("a[rel='example1']").colorbox();
        $("a[rel='example2']").colorbox({ transition: "fade" });
        $("a[rel='example3']").colorbox({ transition: "none", width: "700px", height: "75%" });
        $("a[rel='example4']").colorbox({ slideshow: true });
        $(".example5").colorbox();
        $(".example6").colorbox({ iframe: true, innerWidth: 425, innerHeight: 344 });
        $(".example7").colorbox({ width: "80%", height: "80%", iframe: true });
        $(".example8").colorbox({ width: "600px", inline: true, href: "#inline_example1" });
        $(".example9").colorbox({
            onOpen: function () { alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
            onLoad: function () { alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
            onComplete: function () { alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
            onCleanup: function () { alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
            onClosed: function () { alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

**Code in the content page**

```
<div style='display: none'>
    <div id='inline_example1' style='padding: 10px; background: #fff;'>
        <h2 style="color: #da5f33;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblEventTitle" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></h2>
        <p>
            Please fill out the following form to sign up for the <b>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEventTitle2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></b></p>
        <blockquote>
            <p>
                <b>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Your Name" Width="120px"></asp:Label></b>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="350px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorName" ControlToValidate="txtName"
                    ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" Style="font-size: xx-small;
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: red;"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator><asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                        ID="RequiredFieldValidatorName" Style="font-size: xx-small; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                        color: red;" ControlToValidate="txtName" Text="*" runat="server" /></p>
            <p>
                <b>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblOrganisation" runat="server" Text="Your Organisation" Width="120px"></asp:Label></b>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtOrganisation" runat="server" Width="350px"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
            </p>
            <p>
                <b>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text="Your Email" Width="120px"></asp:Label></b>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Width="350px"></asp:TextBox><asp:RegularExpressionValidator
                    ID="RegularExpressionValidatorEmail" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationExpression="^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$"
                    runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" Style="font-size: xx-small; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    color: red;"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorEmail" Style="font-size: xx-small;
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: red;" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
                    Text="*" runat="server" /></p>
        </blockquote>
        <p>
            <b>Secury Question</b></p>
        <p>
            You must answer this question correctly so we can make sure you are human.</p>
        <blockquote>
            <p>
                <b>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion" runat="server" Text="5 + 5 =" Width="50px"></asp:Label></b>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAnswer" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox><asp:Label
                    ID="lblValidate" runat="server" Width="10px"></asp:Label></p>
        </blockquote>
        <p style="text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Register for Event" /></p>
```

Comment: Does it only fail if you have the script reference (pointing to "http://www.communitysectorservices.org.au/js/jquery.colorbox.js") in the header? If so it's a problem with their script... possibly overriding the button click event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Dynde's lead I was able to fix it:

```
    function appendHTML() {
    if (!$box && document.forms[0]) {
        init = false;

        $window = $(window);
        $box = $tag(div).attr({ id: colorbox, 'class': isIE ? prefix + (isIE6 ? 'IE6' : 'IE') : '' }).hide();
        $overlay = $tag(div, "Overlay", isIE6 ? 'position:absolute' : '').hide();
        $wrap = $tag(div, "Wrapper");
        $content = $tag(div, "Content").append(
            $loaded = $tag(div, "LoadedContent", 'width:0; height:0; overflow:hidden'),
            $loadingOverlay = $tag(div, "LoadingOverlay").add($tag(div, "LoadingGraphic")),
            $title = $tag(div, "Title"),
            $current = $tag(div, "Current"),
            $next = $tag(div, "Next"),
            $prev = $tag(div, "Previous"),
            $slideshow = $tag(div, "Slideshow").bind(event_open, slideshow),
            $close = $tag(div, "Close")
        );

        $wrap.append( // The 3x3 Grid that makes up ColorBox
            $tag(div).append(
                $tag(div, "TopLeft"),
                $topBorder = $tag(div, "TopCenter"),
                $tag(div, "TopRight")
            ),
            $tag(div, false, 'clear:left').append(
                $leftBorder = $tag(div, "MiddleLeft"),
                $content,
                $rightBorder = $tag(div, "MiddleRight")
            ),
            $tag(div, false, 'clear:left').append(
                $tag(div, "BottomLeft"),
                $bottomBorder = $tag(div, "BottomCenter"),
                $tag(div, "BottomRight")
            )
        ).find('div div').css({ 'float': 'left' });

        $loadingBay = $tag(div, false, 'position:absolute; width:9999px; visibility:hidden; display:none');

        $groupControls = $next.add($prev).add($current).add($slideshow);

        $(document.forms[0]).append($overlay, $box.append($wrap, $loadingBay));
    }
}
```

The only 2 lines I changed were the at the beginning and the end of the function:

```
if (!$box && document.forms[0]) {
```

and

```
$(document.forms[0]).append($overlay, $box.append($wrap, $loadingBay));
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked! The only problem; ill never remember to "hack" jquery.colorbox.js again when it's time to upgrade colorbox.

Comment: Yeah, I was worried about that myself. Hopefully they'll fix it sometime.

Comment: Thank you. I have been looking for a solution to this issue for hours. This worked great.

Comment: Working like a charm..I was looking for it for last 3-4 hours

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this:

http://onefishmedia.com/onefishmedia/post/2010/04/29/Getting-ASPNET-Server-Controls-to-work-within-Fancybox-or-Colorbox-plugins.aspx

is what you're looking for.

It happens because the colorbox div is being created outside of the form tag. There's a quick fix in the link - however, in one of the comments it also says it would be easy to implement a parameter for specifying where in the code, you want colorbox to be created - which is what I'd like to do - but it doesn't appear to me, to be so easy :/

Comment: I get invalid viewstate when I try that fix.

Comment: The link appears broken (21-01-2011). Can you elaborate on what the solution was?

Comment: Oh dear, I'm afraid I don't recall the solution. But it should at least guide you in the right direction knowing that the problem is with the main colorbox div is being created outside of the form tag. IIRC you should be able to find the place in the colorbox JS where colorbox is trying to "insert" itself by searching for "body". Change that to an element you but inside the <form> tag. IE: <body><form><div id="ColorboxPlaceHolder">, then change the "body" occurrence in js file to "#ColorboxPlaceHolder" - hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

I has the same problem and solved it on the call of colorbox, moving the colorbox element to the asp.net form:

```
$("a.colorbox").colorbox({
    width: 600,
    onOpen: function () {
        $('#aspnetForm').append($('#colorbox'));
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for easy solution. I'd also add the following line so the overlay doesn't overlap the content.

$('#aspnetForm').append($('#cboxOverlay'));  // <-- Place before the .append($('#colorbox'));